# Azure Batch Service cannot find Az.DataFactory cmdlets when run as a Custom Activity

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-factory, azure-batch

I am attempting to automate the activation of SSIS Integration Runtimes by running a pipeline containing a Custom Activity in Azure Data Factory.

I have set the Batch Service up with a linked storage account and have successfully started to run a .ps1 file in the linked storage account. I know it find the file OK because I can see a node is running and I get an adfjob set of logs in my storage account.

The Powershell script is a simple one liner:

```
Start-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime -Name SSIS -ResourceGroupName <RG Name> -DataFactoryName <ADF Name> -Force
```

However, the output log file says that it cannot find the cmdlet:

> The term 'Start-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime' is  not recognized
>   as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the  spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
>   that the path is correct and try again.

So I take it from the log that Powershell is available on the node but the `Az` module is not.  I find this extremely surprising given it's an Azure Batch Service node.  I've tried adding an `Install-Module Az ...` to the start of this script, the result is it appears to be hanging and I don't know how to track if it is doing anything or not, but in any case I cancelled after 8mins because I'm pretty sure it would have installed by then.

So I am therefore wondering where the Az module should be installed and how to go about doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install the [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-2.8.0) module with your Batch [**Start task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-api-basics#start-task)  in order for your task to use it.

> By associating a start task with a pool, you can prepare the operating environment of its nodes. For example, you can perform actions such as installing the applications that your tasks run, or starting background processes.